# Is this a scam?

Tags: scams

So,a photography page i follow on Instagram made a story post on the person who can answer this riddle "what has 88 keys but can't open a single door" wins 1000$ from the Fidelity company she works with.

Money would be paid to Paypal, but i have to "link" some email, i guess the company's it's something like "giveawayfidelity..."

I feel very fishy about this

Comment: We can't tell you anything more than you already suspect, which is that yes, this is obviously a scam.

Comment: If you can't explain why a company would run a stupid contest that has nothing to do with the product, and it isn't mentioned on the company's own website (not the link in the Instagram message but the one you find by looking it up yourself)... then of course it's a scam.

Comment: Spoiler alert - the answer is "a piano". The answer is still wrong since I'm pretty damn sure that if I got a piano up to speed I'd be able to smash a door open.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is, yes. Yes it is a scam.

They post a super easy riddle with no obvious upside for them. They will ask for your banking information most likely and try to steal money from you or make you an unwitting patsy for a money laundering scheme